# How to pass token value with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift4, alamofire

I am successfully retrieving a token from my API with Alamofire, it is a String. I want take the Token (String) and put it in another request to get some JSON data from the API. But i don't know how to pass it.

```
    var token = String()// global variable

    let parameters = [
       "username" : usernameLabel.text!,
       "password" : passwordLabel.text!
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

    case .Success(let JSON):
        print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

        //example if there is a token
        token = response.objectForKey("token") as! String?
        print(token)

    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"` is the typical authentication header..

Answer (score 1):

try making the call as:

```
var token = String()// global variable

let parameters = [
   "username" : usernameLabel.text!,
   "password" : passwordLabel.text!
]
let headers = [
   "Authorization" : String(format: "Bearer: @%", token)
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
.responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

case .Success(let JSON):
    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

    let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

    //example if there is a token
    token = response.objectForKey("token") as! String?
    print(token)

case .Failure(let error):
    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```